# Split audio files (wav) on Blackberry 10 (native)

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10

I use the following code for record wav file:

```
AudioRecorder recorder; 
recorder.setOutputUrl(<file path...>); 
recorder.record();
```

and for playing
[this tutorial](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/core/play_wav_overview.html)

When wav file is recorded I want to play it and split file when I pause the track.

Could you please help me how can I split wav file?

Answer (score 0):

Write a copy while playing the file. When pausing, close the file and start write a new file and continue the writing by writing to that file instead.

Your record approach seems very high level. If you play file by using something like

```
AudioPlayer player;
player.setInputUrl(...);
player.play();
```

You cannot split the file in that way. You need to do things in your playback loop to get it work.

EDIT:

The comment indicate that you want to do realtime splitting. If so, divide AudioRecorder into two classes:

```
WaveDeviceIn for communication with hardware
WaveFileOut for file output.
```

Then read from WaveDeviceIn as if it were an endless file. Inside your I/O loop you can create and destroy WaveFileOut objects as you wish while recording. Disk I/O may need another thread that is activated when WaveDeviceIn has a new data block to deliver.

Comment: no, I can not close the file and start it during playing.
when I need split the file I have already recorder wav file.
for exm: I have recorder 1.wav file 
I play this file and when I click pause button I want to split it.

Comment: If an AudioRecorder is what I think it is (A class that wraps an audio interface), you do not need any recorder for this. Use some WaveFileWriter instead: Constructor sets header props. Dtor stamps the file size in the header and closes the file.